# Comparing performance - htc vs jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer, html-components

I have a (IE only) web app which now uses htc to render html widgets.

I am considering migrating the app to jQuery. How does the performance compare between
htc and jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a valid question.

.htc files generally use javascript.  jQuery is just a library that sits on top of javascript and gives you some extra functionality.  You could probably even use it *in* an .htc file if you wanted.  So you're basically asking about the performance of jQuery itself.

I never really looked into stats but I can say jQuery is negligibly slower in most cases, if you use your selectors correctly and give them contexts.  It makes cross-browser coding much easier, and is usually worth any minor performance hit.

And if the alternative is using your own homebrew hacked up code, you might see performance improvements instead of performance hits by using jQuery.